# Unity double click does not recognize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to figure the double tap at unity for ios devices, but couldn't succeed it.
Unfortunately, game doesn't recognize the double clicks.

I tried different approaches like pointerdataevent but I like to learn this kind of double click too.

```
 
void Update () 
    {


        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && isGrounded== true)
         {
             for(int i =0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
             Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
             timeTotal+=1;
             Debug.Log(timeTotal);


             if (touch.position.x < Screen.width/2 && (timeDelay < 0.5) && (timeTotal == 2))
             {
                 if(pathManager.randomDirection == 0)
                         {
                                 rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-4, 5, 4), ForceMode.Impulse);
                                 rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                                 timeTotal = 0;
                                 timeDelay =0;
                         }
                 else if(pathManager.randomDirection == 1)
                         {
                                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-4, 5, 4), ForceMode.Impulse);
                                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                                timeTotal = 0;
                                timeDelay =0;
                         }

             }
}

else  if (touch.position.x > Screen.width/2 && (timeDelay > 0.5) && (timeTotal == 1))
             {
                 if(pathManager.randomDirection == 0)
                         {
                                 rb.AddForce(new Vector3(4f, 5f, 8f), ForceMode.Impulse);
                                 rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                                 timeTotal = 0;
                                 timeDelay =0;
                         }
                 else if(pathManager.randomDirection == 1)
                         {
                                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(4f, 5f, 8f), ForceMode.Impulse);
                                rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                                timeTotal = 0;
                                timeDelay =0;
                         }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)? You could start a coroutine on the first tap and detect clicks or taps within your timing tolerance.

Comment: Actually i didn't look to Coroutines. Is the upper way is not good to perform double clicks?